# How do I pre-populate a React Hook form MUI textfield after fetching data from Firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am using React Hook Forms with MUI TextField components.
I am fetching data from Firestore and I would like to prefill the form with this data.

I am using useForm with default value but I'm not really sure how to use it.
I was able to get some of the data on the fields by using a spread operator. I was trying to find a way to de-structure the eventData as an object so I can match the fields with the fetched Data.

Here is the code:

```
const [event, setEvent] = useState('')

const { register, handleSubmit, errors, reset } = useForm({
        resolver: yupResolver(schema),
        defaultValues: {...event}
    })

// get the data to prefill the form
    useEffect(() => {
        getEvent(storyId, eventId, setEvent)  
        reset(event) 
    }, [reset])
```

Here's an example of a TextField

```
<TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        fullWidth
                        id="date"
                        label="date"
                        name="date"
                        autoComplete="date"
                        type="date"
                        autoFocus
                        inputRef={register}
                        error={!!errors.date}
                        helperText={errors?.date?.message}
/>
```

I can confirm that the data object does come in...
[image]

and this is what I get on the form...

[image]

As you can see some of the data is filling the form, but the MUI labels are not shrinking and the text has redability issues. Also since I am not destructuring the eventData, things like the date(which is a date format) and the coordinates which is Firestore geopoint object of latitude and longitude is not being filled in.

A few questions:

1. How do I make sure I set the data in my React component before React-hook-form initializes an object ? I was able to do this with reset. is this best practice?
2. How can I make the MUI label shrink when the form is filled with data?
3. How can I desctructure the eventData and add it to the form?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, uncontrolled  MUI inputs don't reposition their labels if value was set programatically after initial render. Wrap your inputs in `<Controller>` to make them controlled and then everything will be fine. If you need to stay with uncontrolled components the only way I know to make them readable is to use `<TextField InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }} />`.

Take a look here: https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#limitations

Answer (score 0):

1: don't know if this is the best practice. but that's also how I did it.

2: I had the same problem once and setting `defaultValue: ''` in the input solved it, but what @Aitwar answered should help too.

3: create an object with the names of your fields and fill it with the data of eventData. If you can't do it, provide an example on codesandbox and i'll try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can prevent the rendering process by conditional rendering to make sure you already fetched the data.
2. if you want to change the prefill the inputs during the render time, you can add the following props to your input:

`<TextField InputLabelProps={{ shrink: !!getValues('name') }} />`